# Escaping search queries for Google's full text search service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

This is a cross-post of https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/97LY3Yfd_14/discussion

I'm working with the new full text search service in gae 1.6.6 and I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly escape my query strings before I pass them off to the search index. The docs mention that certain characters need to be escaped (namely the [numeric operators](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Numeric_Operators)), however they don't specify *how* the query parser expects the string to be escaped.

The issue I'm having is two-fold:

1. Failing to escape the crap out of many characters (more than those that are hinted at in the docs) will cause the parser to raise a `QueryException`.
2. When I've escaped the query to the point it won't raise, the numeric operators (>, <, >=, <=) no longer parse correctly (not factored into the search).

I setup a test where I feed `string.printable` into `my_index.search()` and found that it would raise `QueryException` on each of the "printable" control characters, which I'm now stripping out, as well as things that would seem innocent like asterisk, comma, parenthesis, braces, tilde. None of these are mentioned in the docs as needing to be escaped.

So far I've tried:

- `cgi.escape()`
- `saxutils.escape()` with a mapping of ascii to urlencoded equivalents (eg `,` -> `%2C`)
- `saxutils.escape()` with a mapping of ascii to html entity encoded ascii codes (eg `&#123;`)
- `urllib.quote_plus()`

I've gotten the best results so far using url-style(`%NN`) replacements, but >, <, >=, and <= continue to fail to yield the expected results from the index. 
Also, and this doesn't really seem to have anything to do with the escaping issue, but using `NOT` in front of a `field = value` type query seems to not be working as advertised either.

#### tl;dr

How should I be escaping my queries before sending them to the search service so that the parser doesn't raise `QueryException` *and* my query yields expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As briefly explained in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Query_Language_Overview), the query parameter is a string that should conform our query language. Which we should document better.

For now, I recommend you to wrap your queries (or at least some of the words/terms) in double quotes. In that way you would be able to pass all printable characters, but `"` and `\`. The following example shows the result.

```
import string
from google.appengine.api.search import Query
Query('"%s"' % string.printable.replace('"', '').replace('\\', ''))
```

and you could even pass non printable characters

```
Query('"%s"' % ''.join(chr(i) for i in xrange(128)).replace('"','').replace('\\', ''))
```

**EDIT**:
Note that anything that is enclosed in double quotes is an exact match, that is "foo bar" would match against ...foo bar... but no ...bar foo..

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a more practical example? Given a query of something like `created >= 2009-20-13 AND description:foobar`, how would you go about escaping that?

Comment: The query you provided does not need to be escaped

    Query('created >= 2009-20-13 AND description:foobar')

just works fine. If you are actually looking for the string 'created >= 2009-20-13 AND description:foobar' in your documents, you should enclose the string in quotes. 

But as a rule I would surround in double quotes any operator defined in the documentation if I want to use them as characters and not operators.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to see. This is indeed contextual (as I alluded to in my groups post). `foo >= 123` works without intervention, but `foo >= 123 > ` will raise an exception. It appears I need to build a pre-parser parser in order to handle this completely. This is... awkward.

Comment: Additionally, the greater than, less than on my date field appears to not work at all, even when providing a civil, well-formed query.

Comment: I assume you are receiving the query string from an end user. Right?

Comment: I kind of see where you're going with that question. I'm now looking at 2 differing contexts for running queries: the 1st is when I'm preparing the query for the user (safe, does not need to be escaped) and the 2nd being queries coming from the user (which I should be brutally stripping of barbs and thorns as it comes in).

Comment: This answer alters the original search term by removing any double-quotes that might actually be part of the query.  Instead I'm using the following replacement successfully, which simply escapes any double-quotes within the search term:  search_term.replace('"', '\\"')

Comment: This answer dates from 2012 and mentions "for now". Is there a better way to do this now? wrapping in quotes is not a desirable solution since it will look for the exact  string