# how to escape special operators/symbols in google app engine search without requiring exact matches?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I escape special operators/symbols in google app engine search queries *without* requiring exact matches?  In particular, I would like to know how to escape the double-quote.

Other special symbols/operators:

- backslash
- single quote
- AND
- OR
- NOT
- ~
- dash
- :
- ,
- <
- >
- plus
- (
- )

The solution described in [Escaping search queries for Google's full text search service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741011/escaping-search-queries-for-googles-full-text-search-service)
suggests enclosing the query in double-quotes, but I do not want to search via an exact match.

E.g. I want the query 'foo bar' to match the string 'bar foo', not just 'foo bar'.

Comment: Given that 's' is the query, I was able to escape only a subset of the operators above in python: s = s.replace('AND','and'), s = s.replace('OR','or'), s = s.replace('NOT','not'), s = s.replace('-','\\\\-'),  s = s.replace('<','\\<'), s = s.replace('+','\\+'), s = s.replace('>','\\>').  This was discovered through trial and error (versus any official Google documentation).  I wish Google would document this officially.

Comment: Note the above works only for a locally-dev_appserver and in ferris3 unit tests.  I.e., there seems to be a bug for local gae deployments where the symbols dash, less than, greater than, and plus are escapable and searchable through a query, and indexed in the document.  On a real cloud deployment, these symbols do not seem searchable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special symbols you list do not need to be escaped, exactly. The search API strips out most of the characters you list when indexing documents, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Special_treatment_of_string_and_date_fields), so it would do no good to include them in a query string. In fact, they are also stripped from query strings in many situations, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings#Python_Tokenization). So there is no special handling needed in most cases; the search API will ignore them both in the document and in the query.

You may need to make sure they do not interefere with the query itself, though. For example parentheses will not be stripped from a query string, but rather group queries. This is my algorithm for sanitizing user-entered strings to pass along to the search API. It may not be complete, and it may not be what you want, but it could be a starting point for you:

1. If the string contains only punctuation and whitespace, return no results (otherwise the search API will return all documents)
2. Replace these characters with a space: `:<>=()~,`
3. Make the entire query lower case (this avoids `AND` and `OR` being treated as boolean operators, as you already discovered, and searches are case-insensitive anyway)
4. If there are an odd number of `"` characters, append one more (I forget why...this may only be because I add more terms to the user-entered query string)

You mention wanted to "escape" the `"` character. I suggest replacing it with a space, instead, if you don't want users to be able to specify exact matching.

If you find more things that should be added to this list, please let me know!